# Renaming an OpenVPN server - how to keep from losing all clients?

Tags: openvpn, puppet

I have been instructed to change the domain name on a bank of servers. One of these is for OpenVPN and I'm wondering how best to do this without cutting off all the clients.

Each client is also running **puppet** so I can update the .conf files. Unf puppet isn't great for solutions like "do this for a while.. now stop doing that and do this instead." It seems to be better suited to "always do this".

** it should be noted that puppet is using the VPN to communicate so it's possible to make a change that cuts off its ability to make any further changes.

Some possibilities:

1. Setup a VM with the new VPN name. Update the clients to point to this. Rename the original machine and update the clients again.
2. Add a second VPN server instance on the original machine via a different (non-default) port. Do the same double renaming while shuffling the server name about.
3. Update all the VPN clients with the new address of the server. They will lose contact with the server until the server address is changed.

Option 3 seems like the most direct but the one that also bothers me the most. The VPN clients are scattered throughout the city and it would be a monumental hassle to hit them all individually to fix a huge outage.

Am I just being fussy? Is there an option 4 that makes more sense?

Comment: Apart from a DNS-resolving entry in the config file, which can easily be dealt with as the old and new FQDNs may lawfully point to the same IP address, I'm not aware that clients have any dependency on the server's hostname.  Can anyone enlighten me?